# Unable to send var.click(); successfully to web player

Tags: javascript, html, web, tampermonkey, userscripts

I have made a very basic script that I made for my rasPi to run music from player.siriusxm.com that sends a click event to the play button. The script used to work without issue but only works IF I interact with the page first before sending the event. This has been one of the scripts I've been managing to learn JS but this has me stumped. Any help is appreciated!

What it should do:  Check Ready state of page > Issue Click to play button.

What happens: the click event is sent to the button but does not 'work' & hangs the button until page refresh.

How to get it to work: Can only work AFTER any page element is interacted (click/keypress).

I have tried to issue a DOMKeypress, Focus the button but to no avail.

```
/* defines play/pause button */
let bTn0=document.getElementsByClassName('play-pause-btn');

function init(){
    console.log('init0')
    var rS0=document.readyState;
    if (rS0 === 'complete'){
        console.log('init1')
        main(); }
    else{
        console.log('init2')
        setTimeout(() => {
            init();
        }, 3*1000) }}
function main(){
        console.log('main0');
    if (bTn0.item('').title === 'Play'){
        console.log('main1');
            bTn0.item('').click(); }
    if (bTn0.item('').title === 'Pause'){
        console.log('main2'); }
    /*else{
        console.log('main3');
        setTimeout(() => {
            init();
        }, 3*1000) }*/}
console.log('OOB');
setTimeout(() => {
    init();
}, 3*1000)
```

Comment: Think about the implications/problems that would arise when a script could just "click" on something without "consent" (active interaction) from the user?

Comment: Use devtools -> Event listeners panel in element inspector to find which events the page listens to, and see what it does on that first click, then imitate it. @Andreas, userscripts are a part of user agent.